# Slider Is Acting Funny

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I have a [slider](http://www.eclectogroove.com/new-site) that is not working. The first problem is when you click on the arrow buttons to go to the next slide I get these errors in my console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null tabs.js:43
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js:352
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js:352
GET http://localhost/eclectogroove/undefined 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:127
GET http://localhost/eclectogroove/undefined 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:130
GET http://localhost/eclectogroove/undefined 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:130
```

I don't know why I am getting these errors but another problem is the image on the slider will randomly disappear after about 20 seconds.

Here is the code from tabs.js

```
init:function(tabid, dselected){
var menuitems=document.getElementById(tabid).getElementsByTagName("a")
this[tabid+"-menuitems"]=menuitems
for (var x=0; x<menuitems.length; x++){
    if (menuitems[x].getAttribute("rel")){
        this[tabid+"-menuitems"][x].hasSubContent=true
        if (menuscript.disabletablinks)
            menuitems[x].onclick=function(){return false}
    }
    else //for items without a submenu, add onMouseout effect
        menuitems[x].onmouseout=function(){this.className=""}
    menuitems[x].onclick=function(){menuscript.showsubmenu(tabid, this)}
    if (dselected=="auto" && typeof setalready=="undefined" && this.isSelected(menuitems[x].href)){
        menuscript.showsubmenu(tabid, menuitems[x])
        var setalready=true
    }
    else if (parseInt(dselected)==x)
        menuscript.showsubmenu(tabid, menuitems[x])
}
```

}

If you need me to post any code or supply you with any other information please let me know. Otherwise everything can be seen [here](http://www.eclectogroove.com/new-site).

Comment: You could just call it "Funny Slider" and sell it on Code Canyon ?

Comment: There is no element with id `albums`. Thats why you get that first message

Comment: @stackErr You are right, I found the same using the debugger of Chrome. Consider writing an answer.

Comment: @kol we still havent solved the mCustomScrollbar error

Comment: @stackErr so how would I fix the first issue? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `tabs.js` file.

You are calling:
`menuscript.definemenu("albums", 0)` (last line in the file)
but there is no element with id `albums`.

This calls the `init` function and at line 43:

```
var menuitems=document.getElementById(tabid).getElementsByTagName("a")
```

where `var menuitems=document.getElementById(tabid)` returns `null`. 
Hence the error `Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null tabs.js:43`

To solve this either create an element with id `albums` or just delete this:
`menuscript.definemenu("albums", 0)`

FYI, get into the habit of ending a JS statement with a semicolon(`;`)...its very sloppy programming.

Comment: So how would this be fixed?

Comment: @cdell Edited my answer. Also this happens on page load, not when you click the button.

Comment: thank you again! I updated that however I am still having issues. The image on the slider still disappears after 10-20 seconds. And I get this error in my console still. GET http://localhost/eclectogroove/undefined 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:127

Comment: Both of those things are related....you only have one picture on your website, the slider tries to look for the next picture and finds that there are none.

Comment: I suggest you understand the code you have rather than asking on stackoverflow. We dont do your work for you